# Should request payment details for a project I am to do?

Tags: etiquette, funding

I am a Master's student. Recently, my professor offered me a project mentioning that funding has been granted for the project and that I will be getting paid for my work. I would like to know if I can ask him the exact amount and if yes, what will be the polite way to ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compensation is an integral part of the decision to take on any job. Not only should you know the amount ahead of time, but also the mode of compensation: is it 1k up front? Is it $10/hour? Is it $500 now and $500 at the end of the project? This is information that you are owed as a prospective employee.

You should just be straightforward about this. There’s no decorum that you need to follow outside of whatever is usual in your relationship. I would write something along these lines:

> Hi James,
>
> I’m excited about the research opportunity that you mentioned after class last week. I was hoping you could fill me in on some concrete details such as when and how much I will be paid, the expected project timeline, the scope of my part of the project, and who else would be involved.
>
> If you don’t have these details set yet, I totally understand. In that case, do you have an idea of when you will have them?
>
> Thanks,
>   Stella

I’ve sent some variant of this email tons of times. I’m somewhat making up the details, as I don’t know what you have or have no discusses with this professor, but I would strongly recommend that you ask about any of the things that I have listed that you don’t know already. If this is a project that is part of publishable research, you should also ask about authorship and (if applicable to your field) authorship order.

Comment: I really like this answer. Keep in mind though, that for some people in academia, money is seen as somewhat of a "dirty" topic. It is of course quite easy for a tenured professor to think that we're not in it for the money. Therefore: Remember that compensation should not be the only thing in the email.

Comment: @nabia That is a good point, and I think an important consideration in asking **if it will be funded**. However, I would expect this to not be much of a concern since the professor seemed to volunteer that the position would be funded.

Answer (score 1):

In many institutions covered by employment law  your professor would have to conform to university protocols to employ you, which would include some kind of contract explicitly defining your terms and conditions. Even 'casual work' where you do not become a true employee is often subject to proper scrutiny by the university to protect both the worker and the institution from exploitation or malpractice.

You have every right to expect a clear indication of your pay, and the duration of the paid work before you consent to undertake it. Beware of false promises and unofficial deals that could undermine your rights and safety.

I understand the situation is delicate given you need to work with your professor regardless of this job, but it is unprofessional of him/her to not properly communicate and be opaque with regard to the discussions you previously had.